# In Australia can you take Personal leave to look after a sick child or partner?

Tags: employment, australia

Under Australian employment law are you allowed to take personal leave to look after a sick child or partner?

Is personal leave the correct category or does it depend on employment terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Australian government itself](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/how-we-will-help/templates-and-guides/fact-sheets/minimum-workplace-entitlements/personal-leave-and-compassionate-leave#personal-carers-leave), not only children and partners, and not only for sickness, but all immediate family of the employee (and of their partner if applicable) and for "unexpected emergencies" as well.

> An employee may take paid personal/carer’s leave:
>
> - if they are unfit for work because of their own personal illness or injury (including pregnancy-related illness), or
> - to provide care or support to a member of their immediate family or household, because of a personal illness, injury or unexpected emergency affecting the member. A member of the employee’s immediate family means a spouse, de facto partner, child, parent, grandparent, grandchild or sibling of an employee; or a child, parent, grandparent, grandchild or sibling of the employee’s spouse or de facto partner.